# Return rows from db that iterates through multiple column string delimited by semicolon

Tags: sql-server

I am using easyquery to perform search on a table in db. This table has got multiple columns having string delimited by semicolon. each delimited string belongs to different transaction. Rightnow the search looks into the whole string and returns row that belongs to different transaction. What I need to do is For eg: From the snapshot column 1 should take only the 1st string, column 2 1st string, column 3 1st string, column 4 1st string likewise all columns that has multiple strings that belong to different transaction. Finally I need to only return the rows that belong to same record as search result.

I am aware that it requires some sql function to do this job. I need some suggestion how this can he approached.

[image]

Comment: Very poor database design. Breakout the strings into columns and rows appropriate to what you are describing. It will make it easier in the end to report on. Use a split function to separate the string column data.

Comment: yes I agree that it is a poor db design. This is what the company is using for a long time. Now they are facing issues due to this poor design.

Comment: You are going to need a string splitter since you can't fix that horrible design. Here is my first choice. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ This may be good for you since you need to know the order. Here are several other excellent choices but none of them return the position within the delimited string. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings